# non-standard find method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usually when you call `root.find('.test')`, it'll return all elements with `test` class *inside* `root`.  Is there any way to consider `root` as possible candidate too?

In other words, with html

```
<div id="x" class="test"></div>
```

, `$('#x').find('.test')` would return 1 element instead of zero.

If we generalize it, in expression `root.find('condition1 condition2 condition3')` I would like `condition1` to be tested against `root` also.

I'm considering creating a custom helper method, but maybe there's something more elegant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There's no *clean* way to do this, the closest you can get is using [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) like this:

```
$('#x').find('.test').andSelf().filter('.test')
```

It would be slightly cleaner (and more efficient, without the double filtering) if [`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) took a selector, but would only be a bit shorter.

The *fastest* (but a bit messier) way with built-in methods involves duplicating the ID selector, like this:

```
$('#x').find('.test').add($('#x').filter('.test'));
//or, shorter but slower:
$('#x').find('.test').add($('#x.test'));
```

[You can compare the performance of all 3 here](http://jsperf.com/self-selector-comparison).

Comment: +1, after hacking this one out in my brain, this is the only nice way to do it.

Comment: @Stephen I wouldn't call this monstrosity 'nice' :)  Anyway, looks like Nick is correct and there's no direct solution.

Comment: @Nick Many. Working with composite selector would be nice too.

Comment: @Nikita - A generic form would look like this: `$.fn.findAndSelf = function(selector) { return this.find(selector).add(this.filter(selector)); };`, you can test it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/PsmAS/

Comment: Thanks for the jsPerf Nick, I was just getting ready to make one myself :)

Comment: That's nice, but doesn't really work if you're looking for `.elephant .trunk` and your current element may already be an elephant or a whole herd of elephants. I'm considering checking if current element is elephant inside findAndSelf (first condition in composite selector) and in this case invoking `find` on rest of the selector (`.trunk .nostril ...`).

Comment: @Nikita - That's another option, though it'll be complicated by `:has()` and `:not()` selectors :) It's not an easy question as to *how* this should work, probably why it was never added to core.

Comment: @Nikita - That's what my answer that did the split / loop over the array does very crudely, but it would break with some selectors (and pretty badly)

Comment: @Nick It doesn't have to be complicated: we can as easily use `if` and string functions inside `$.fn.findAndSelf`. As for *how*... I meant it to be like `root.parent().find('...')` in case `root.parent()` has only one child.

Comment: @Nikita - you could use `root.parent().find(...)` and a filter on `$.contains(root, results)` if that's the route you're after.

Comment: Thanks to both of you :) I'll probably get back to this question when I have more free time to fiddle with it and complete `findAndSelf`. Right now it doesn't seem like a good idea to use this in production code.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what I think you're asking... You want `.find('.test a')` to only search for  `a` if the element you are searching on is already a `.test`...

Here's my attempt at that functionality:

```
$.fn.search = function(selector) {
    selector = selector || '';
    var parts = selector.split(/\s+/),
        l = parts.length,
        iAm = '',
        find = '';
    for (var x = l; x > 0; x--) {
        // countning backwards from the end of the list
        iAm = parts.slice(0, x).join(' ');
        find = parts.slice(x).join(' ');
        // if the 'iAm' portion of the selector matches this element
        if (this.is(iAm)) {
            // if there is no find portion (because we are the full selector) return ourself
            // but add the children that also match the last portion of the selector
            if (!find) return this.add(this.find(parts.slice(l-1).join('')));
            // return the .find() using only the parts of the selector needed
            return this.find(find);
        }
    }

    // otherwise, resort to original .find()
    return this.find(selector);
}
```

[And the test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/aH4rQ/3/)

Of course, because of the way this splits up the selector parts (`.split(/\s+/)`) its going to break for selectors that have spaces in them for other reasons like `.something:has(.another .thing)` or `.something[value='1 2']` type selectors couldn't be used with this function

Comment: +1 to both of your answers (and Nick), it'll give me something to exercise my brain :)

Comment: this doesn't work in other cases, for example:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uCQ3P/

Comment: @Nick - Good point... I think the other solution works out a bit better, but this was one possible implementation idea.

Comment: @Nick - Since this seems much faster than the other method - I updated the `return this` to add a search for the last part of the selector as well

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your case has something like this:

```
<div class="this">
    <div class="is" id="test">
        <div class="a">
            <div class="test">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you have a `var $test = $('#test')`.
You want to `$test.find('.this .is .a .test')` and get a reference to that inner div.

```
$.fn.search = function(selector) { return this.find('*').andSelf().filter(selector); }
```

Then you can `$test.search('.this .is .a .test')` and get a reference to the inner div! [Demonstrated in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/n79ed/)

Of course, this is way slower than just `.find()` with the correct selector...

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with your previous answer? You caught my intent correctly, I'm testing it right now.

Comment: The code for this one is much smaller, and will return the same thing ;) -- The old answer might be a little speedier though... Hard to say...

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know 'filter' works like that! Let me try it.

Comment: @nikita - I undeleted the old answer for you too... :)

Comment: The data from the jsPerf's I've run seem to indicate this method is  as slow as I thought it would be... As much as 61% slower than the other http://jsperf.com/self-selector-comparison/2

Answer (score 1):

use a dynamic parent and find it's contents. This could be wrapped in a plugin.

```
$('#x').wrap('<div />').parent()
    .find('.test').css('margin-left', '20px') // affected have m-left: 20
.end().children().unwrap();
```

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rGttu/)